# ReferenceError: describe is not defined in Jest + Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Simple configuration of Jest with ts-jest produces error "ReferenceError: describe is not defined" in runtime. Here minimal example: https://github.com/PFight/jest-ts-describe-not-defined-problem

What I configured wrong?

Comment: There are many possible jest ts configurations that just work. Why not use one of them ??

Comment: I have used the first configuration that google found. Can you recomend another one, that I missed?

Comment: I suggested tring 3 first found. And if none work then check most frequently asked question that combine jest + describe is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem but I needed the testEnvironment to be node. The solution is to downgrade to `"jest": "^24.9.0"`. It seems like there's a problem with the latest version when testEnvironment is set to node.

**UPDATE**

It looks like this issue has been fixed in jest 25.2.2 per this comment https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9538#issuecomment-604522345
I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 8):

I had same problem in node v10.14.1.

Just update node to v10.16.2 and error was fixed.

Comment: Fixed it for me. To be clear, I just upgraded to the latest node version, not explicitly 10.16.2 :)

Answer (score 7):

Found the problem. It was next row in jest.config.js:

```
testEnvironment: 'node',
```

Just removed it and error was fixed.

Comment: I recommend reading the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string. Perhaps you need to use a different node version and keep that setting

Answer (score 3):

Or you can add the type definitions for jest like this in your tsconfig:
`"include": ["node_modules/@types", "test/**/**.ts"],`

And add the types via installing it with npm -i **@types/jest**

I can't push to your repo though creating a PR is not possible..

Comment: @types/jest installed and types: ["jest"] specified in tsconfig.json. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer help you fix your problem?

Comment: Another answer authored by me is already solved the problem. I can' accept it within two days, due to rules of stackoverflow... Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0):

Wired answer but may help someone. but in my case `@types`, `tsconfig`, and everything was ok and I still have the error, by the end, I figured that `spec` and `test` are in `exclude` array in `tsconfig` removed it and the error is gone.