# Is it possible to put test files under pages directory in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, next.js

I'm writing integration tests for the API routes in a Next.js application and I'm wondering if there is any problem with putting the `index.test.ts` file under the `/pages` directory. I'd prefer the test to be as close to the file as possible rather than having to map the project structure inside `__test__` directory.

`./pages/api/path/index.ts`

```
handler.get(async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  ...
});

export default  handler;
```

`./pages/api/path/index.test.ts`

```
import { testClient } from "__test__/utils/testClient";

describe("Testing API  POST: /api", () => {
  test("Should return 401 when not authenticated", async () => {
    const request = testClient({ handler });
    const res = await request.post("/api/applications");
    expect(res.status).toEqual(401);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**TL;DR:** While not possible by default, you can co-locate test files inside the `pages` folder by customising the `pageExtensions` option in `next.config.js`.

---

By default, Next.js will take into account any file ending with `tsx`, `ts`, `jsx` or `js` under the `pages` folder for the purpose of building pages/API routes and routing.

From the [Custom Page Extensions](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions#including-non-page-files-in-the-pages-directory) documentation:

> Next.js assumes every tsx/ts/jsx/js file in the `pages` directory is a
> page or API route, and may expose unintended routes vulnerable to
> denial of service attacks, or throw an error like the following when
> building the production bundle

Adding a file named `index.test.ts` in the `pages` folder (or any subfolder) will include that file as an actual page, and potentially throw errors during build time.

You can circumvent this by modifying the extensions Next.js expects using the `pageExtensions` property in `next.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
    // Default value is ['tsx', 'ts', 'jsx', 'js']
    pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js']
}
```

With this configuration, only pages with the above extensions will be taken into account. So you could have the following `pages` folder structure, with co-located test files.

```
pages/
├─ api/
│   ├─ path.page.ts
│   └─ path.test.ts
├─ _app.page.ts
├─ _document.page.ts
├─ index.page.ts
└─ index.test.ts
```

Both `path.test.ts` and `index.test.ts` would be ignored.

Comment: That's a good solution and helps maintaining tests in the correct locations.