# trying to get jest to work with typescript getting describe, it, afterAll, expect is undefined

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Trying to setup jest with typescript and my linter is giving me a few red squiggly lines with describe, it, afterAll saying they are undefined.

I tried some solutions here [ReferenceError: describe is not defined in Jest + Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927799/referenceerror-describe-is-not-defined-in-jest-typescript) but they haven't worked.

my versions

```
node: 12.16.3
"@types/jest": "^26.0.7"
"jest": "^26.1.0",
"ts-jest": "^26.1.4",
"typescript": "^3.9.7"
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "__test__/db/**/**.ts"
  ]
}
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'jsx', 'tsx'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)'],
  testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```

and my root **tests** folder looks like this

```
__test__
  db
    tables
      users.test.ts
```

and a snippet of my test file that should be enough:

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';

describe('users table', (): void => {
  const conString: string = 'postgres://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/testdb';
```

And just incase my .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'airbnb',
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  env: {
    node: true,
    es6: true
  },
  rules: {
    'implicit-arrow-linebreak': 'off',
    'comma-dangle': 'off',
    indent: 'off',
    'no-trailing-spaces': 'off'
  },
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint'
  ]
};
```

Any ideas where I am off? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Adding jest: true to the env object inside .eslintrc.js solved it.